# angularfire2 set the title of an object by dynamic data content

Tags: typescript, angularfire2

is it possible to set the name of an object with a string variable?

For example:

```
car: {
  brands: {
    var1: {}, 
/*where var1 is a model and want to add some more models in different spaces in time.*/
  }
}
```

This is the query I imagined would work:

```
addBrand (var1) {
  var brandRef = firebase.database () .ref ().child ('car/brands');
    brandRef.set ({
      var1: {} 
    });
}
```

The output I get is the text `var1`, not its value.

Is there any way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

You can do this:

```
addBrandInfo (brandName, brandInfo) {
  let brandRef = firebase.database().ref(`car/brands/${brandName}`);
  brandRef.set(brandInfo);
}

updateBrandInfo (brandName, brandInfo) {
  let brandRef = firebase.database().ref(`car/brands/${brandName}`);
  brandRef.update(brandInfo);
}
```

The following section attempts to show by example how each call affects firebase:

```
// Let's assume your firebase is empty.

addBrandInfo('tesla', { established: 2003, founder: 'Elon Musk' });
// car: {
//   brands: {
//     tesla: { established: 2003, founder: 'Elon Musk' }
//   }
// }

addBrandInfo('ford', { established: 1905, founder: 'Henry Ford' });
// car: {
//   brands: {
//     ford: { established: 1905, founder: 'Henry Ford' },
//     tesla: { established: 2003, founder: 'Elon Musk' }
//   }
// }

updateBrandInfo('ford', { established: 1903 });
// car: {
//   brands: {
//     ford: { established: 1903, founder: 'Henry Ford' },
//     tesla: { established: 2003, founder: 'Elon Musk' }
//   }
// }
```

Notice how the last call `updateBrandInfo()` only updates ford's established year, but it leaves the founder `Henry Ford` alone.

**CAUTION** The single quote looking thing around `car/brands/${brandName}` is a back tick and **NOT** a single quote.

Comment: You can use `.update(setInfo)` to add to your existing data.

Comment: I think `setInfo = {};` is deleting the previous content making it impossible to store more than one brand.

Comment: If you ran these calls, it will add to your car brands and it *won't* erase the previous ones. `brandRef.update({ volvo: true });`, `brandRef.update({ tesla: true });` If you execute `brandRef.set({});` afterwards, it will set `car/brands` to {}, which will essentially clear out the object at that reference. Hope that clears it up a bit more.

Comment: Here are the docs about the [`update` call](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#update).

Comment: Don't quite understand. Could you update the code in your answer? If the user refreshes the page, it should start all over again according to what I understood. And I should query all the brands that the user ever entered.

Comment: Sure thing. Before I update the answer, I wanted to ask you about the empty string you are setting as the values. Is there any reason why you would want that, instead of actual brand data associated with the specific brand?

Comment: Sure, sorry for the delay, it was almost 3 am and I felt asleep. I want an Admin to set some brands and after that add some car models in different components.

Comment: I commented the code trying to explain what you just asked, just in case you don't understand correctly my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

What I did is:

```
let brandRef = firebase.database () .ref ().child ('car/brands');
brandRef.child (var1).set ({
  whatever: ''
});
```

Works perfectly!

Comment: If you just want a primitive string, you will want this instead: `brandRef.chid(var1).set('whatever string');` In your example above it will add another object at `car/brands/<var1>` instead of just an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

With [Angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md) try a method like below:

```
addbrand (var1, value) {
     const toSend = this.af.database.object(`/car/brands/${var1}`);
     toSend.set(value);
}
```